# ActionBarCompat with Progressbar

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am currently strugeling with the ProgressBar in the ActionBar.
If I try

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS|Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); 


mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
setContentView(mViewPager);
```

This throws an

> call requestWindowFeature before setContentView

If I put supportRequestWindowFeature right before the super.onCreate it throws a NullPointer-Exception.
If I only use one Feature it either works on Android 2.3.3 or 4.4.2 (currently available devices) with laster configuration. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss the correct way to init it.Here is code from [AndroidDeveloper](http://android-developers.blogspot.tw/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Needs to be called before setting the content view
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    // Now set the content view
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    // When ready, show the indeterminate progress bar
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
}
```

Comment: This makes it crash due to **requestFeature before setContent**

Comment: have you set super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) before supportRequestWindowFeature? And do this stuff (mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);) before setContentView is that right?

Comment: Ok, I tried around some bit. The Code you copied worked for 2.3.3 but not for 4.4.2. I had to call supportRequestWindowFeature BEFORE super.onCreate to make it work. Weird behaviour but it seems to do the trick.

Comment: Oh,it seems we have to use api branch to do this.